# Getting different results each time I run RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, random-forest, non-deterministic

I use this code hoping to achieve determinism:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
np.random.seed(0)
import random
random.seed(0)

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, criterion='mse', min_samples_leaf=4)
```

But my results are not deterministic. Why is this, and how can I address it?

Comment: You need to add `random_state` into your regression model

Comment: you probably want to use the random_state parameter in the RFRegressor call.

Comment: You should add the `np.random.seed()` on top of your script before importing the RandomForestRegressor.

Comment: @Baron see my answer and let us know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use the `random_state` argument in the `RandomForestRegressor`:**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, criterion='mse', min_samples_leaf=4, 
                           random_state= 0)
```

**This should return the same results every single time.**

---

> Scikit-learn does not use its own global random state; whenever a
>   RandomState instance or an integer random seed is not provided as an
>   argument, it relies on the numpy global random state, which can be set
>   using numpy.random.seed

---

That being said, **adding** `np.random.seed()` **before** **importing** the `RandomForestRegressor` **should also do the trick.**

Source: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution